# Gradient (spherical) on combined surfaces not working

Tags: texturing

I am attempting to apply a spherical gradient texture to two combined surfaces with the aim to blend out the plane edges. The problem i am running into is I cannot get the gradient to appear. Instead there are black areas near the planes edges.

The first image is my issue visually and my node step up for the gradient.

The second image is my entire node setup for the combined surfaces, a noise texture, and the gradient texture.

Thank you to anyone who can shed light on this. Thank you for your time.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If your aim is to have the gradient make the textures you have mixed "fade off" into the distance, then your problem is likely that you have your **Blend Mode** set to *Opaque*. Change it to something like *Alpha Blend*. See Below:

[image: AlphaBlend]

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you so much Christopher Bennett for shedding light on this concern. This has helped me tremendously.